# Enable dual monitor on a broken screen

Tags: xrandr

Ive installed Ubuntu on a notebook with a broken display with the help of an external monitor. When booting, the external monitor shows everything fine, but when the login appears, it stops output to the monitor.

It seems that I can configure my outputs through xrandr, but I cannot see anything happening and I cannot also even check if the console is open to accept commands (tried ctrl alt T).

I have also tried xrandr --output VGA1 --auto from another question posted here, but nothing seemed to happen (tried with VGA1, VGA0, VGA-1 and VGA-0 too).

Does anyone have any idea how to work this around?

Answer (score 1):

On my laptop, in the displays settings dialog, I have the ability to select either display, then turn it on or off with the switch under the graphic (ipod-style on-off switch).  If I turn off the one for the laptop, next time I boot, it will not display, even if the other monitor is not connected - I found this out the hard way, of course. :)

This is using the standard settings dialog with a default driver on an old Thinkpad.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of solved this by not installing the nVidia drivers. My machine runs very sluggish for graphical applications, but at least I was able to see what was going on in the external monitor.